# Statement Insert

Tags: sql-server, database, insert

I want to insert a record in my table in SQLServer database.

The code is:

```
INSERT INTO UserControlMaster (UsercontrolID,Usrid,ModuleID, Allow_add,Allow_edit,Allow_Delete) VALUES((select (max(UsercontrolID)+1) from UsercontrolMaster), 1, 2, 0,0,0)
```

On execution it says

> Sub queries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions
>   are allowed.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You're not allowed to use a sub-query where you are trying to — like the error message says.  It looks as though you're trying to simulate an auto-incremented column the hard way; there's usually an alternative, but the details vary between DBMS and I don't use SQL Server so I don't know what you need to do there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserControlMaster 
(
      UsercontrolID
    , Usrid
    , ModuleID
    , Allow_add
    , Allow_edit
    , Allow_Delete
)
SELECT 
      MAX(UsercontrolID) + 1
    , 1
    , 2
    , 0
    , 0
    , 0
FROM dbo.UsercontrolMaster
```